# Output capacitor PCB layout

Tags: voltage, capacitor, pcb, voltage-regulator, layout

I am routing a 4 layer PCB of a buck-boost switching voltage regulator circuit. Space is limited and my input & output caps are large. Is there anything to look out for if I lay out the output and input caps like in the picture? Should they all be orientated in the same direction? I can not see an issue with this layout.

For reference the caps are 1206. I can extend the PCB but I'd rather not do that.

[image]

Comment: Are those SOT-23 MOSFETs? If you are low on space, a fully integrated regulator is a better option.

Comment: Schematic required. Data sheet link to the controller also (and any other silicon used).